# template specialization call by reference

Tags: c++, templates

To understand more about C++ templates, I was reading a book (C++ templates : the complate guide) and can't understand an explanation.

```
// basics/max3a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

// maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

// maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value)
inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a;
}

// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c); // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}

int main ()
{
    ::max(7, 42, 68); // OK
    const char* s1 = "frederic";
    const char* s2 = "anica";
    const char* s3 = "lucas";
    ::max(s1, s2, s3); // ERROR
}
```

The book says,

"
The problem is that if you call max() for three C-strings, the statement

```
return max (max(a,b), c);
```

becomes an error. This is because for C-strings, max(a,b) creates a new, temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference.
"

I understand max(s1, s2, s3) is called by reference arguments, but inside the max-of-three function, max(a,b) is using the call-by-value function(because it's more speicialized). and the temporary return value max(a,b) is a value(in stack) and there is no max(value, reference) function. Isn't that the problem? I can't understand the book's text saying `... becomes an error. This is because for C-strings, max(a,b) creates a new, temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference`.

Comment: small change http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b4a6b1387a8cd20a

Comment: I get `max.cpp:23: warning: returning reference to temporary`. (g++ 4.4.7).  sounds like  the max(a,b) is reurning reference, meaning the first max( T const& a, T const& b) is used. No error in my case either.

Comment: problem is with lvalue and rvalue reference

Comment: the original code works. With `std::cout << "working : " << ::max(s1,s2,s3) << std::endl;` it produces `working : lucas`. What's wrong exactly? I think the author says we should have specialized the max function using call by reference also for the char string case.

Comment: please make sure to indent your code when you ask a question

Comment: Note that this problem is always something to look out for with a function that returns by reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and the temporary return value max(a,b) is a value(in stack)

No, the return value is not "in stack". It's a value, period. Full stop:

```
inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
```

This returns a value. In the caller's context, it's a temporary value. Now, let's proceed to the next step:

```
return max (max(a,b), c); //
```

In this template, this `return` returns a reference. The refence is to the value returned by this call to `max()`, which, in this context, is a temporary value.

This temporary value goes out of scope and gets destroyed when this function call returns. Which it does, and it returns a reference to a destroyed value. De-referencing this reference becomes undefined behavior.

This has nothing to do with templates, and specialization. This would also be true with equivalent, non-template code.

Comment: Ok, understand. I guess the text in the books should read then, `temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference` ==> `temporary local value that may be returned by the function as  reference`

Comment: by the way, I understand values passed or returned between functions use stack, stack frame incrementing or decrementing when calling or returning and use a location in the stack frame according to ABI(application binary interface) rule. Isn't it true?

Comment: It may be true, but is utterly irrelevant. This is up to a particular C++ implementation how it wants to implement function returns. The C++ standard actually ***requires*** the temporary value to be destroyed. Whether it originally arrived in a stack frame, or a CPU register, is something nobody really cares about. It's gone. It expired. It ceased to be. It joined the choir invisible. It's gone to meet its maker. It's an ex-value. So keeping a reference to it, and using it after the return from the function, is guaranteed undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I understand it because the stack frame is gone. it's automatic variable living only during the function.